# What is the rationale behind "inline function need to be DEFINED in all tranlation units"?

Tags: c++, function, inline

I read this line in Stroustrup's book:
**"An i n l i n e function (§7.1.1, §10.2.9) must be defined – by identical definitions (§9.2.3) – in every translation unit in which it is used."**

What is the rationale behind "inline function need to be DEFINED in all tranlation units"?
Am I understanding it incorrectly? I know that with other functions declarations in all the translation units except one(that contains definition) would be fine.

Comment: Can it be to support seperate compilation? Every translation unit can be compiled in isolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, C++ language compilers were built on principles of independent translation. Each translation unit is compiled completely independently (and only the linker sees the entire program).

Under these circumstances, in order to perform inlining the compiler has to be able to see the *source code* of the function in each translation unit where it is called. For that, it has to be *defined* (i.e. declared with a body) in each translation unit.

Comment: Makes sense, but doesn't answer the question. Since `inline` is just a hint anyway, it would have been trivial to state that the hint is only meaningful if a definition is provided.

Comment: @MSalters: Andrey's answer looks fine, as linking would come into picture after the compilation. At the time of compilation if the compiler decides to expand an inline function, it must have the definition present within the translation unit that is being compiled.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1610930: The compiler would know whether it *can* inline, before deciding to do so. If it lacked a definition in a certain tranlation unit, it would just put in an unresolved symbol and let the linker resolve it. Hence, if the rule had not existed, an `inline` function would be inlined only in those translation units that contained a definition. Unambiguous rule, perfectly workable, and doesn't break independent translation at all.

Comment: @MSalters: What you describe is indeed a viable and logical approach to implementing inline function support (if I'm not missing anything, this is how it is done in C99). However, this is not the approach used in C++. C++ follows a *different* approach, also viable and logical in its own way. What I don't see though is why you believe the original question was about this specifically.

Comment: @AndreyT: The question is about the rationale for the C++ rule - _why_. Your answer states that the reason was independent translation, but my example shows that the rule is not necessary for independent translation. Then why does it exists? See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An inline function can be defined multiple times in multiple translation units, so if it was used in one where it was not defined, the linker would not know which definition to use. (This could obviously be solved, but it would result in extra complexity for the linker, and would not have any significant advantages.)

Comment: It wouldn't matter which definition is used, since they all have to be identical anyway. This is typically solved by the existing "Pick Any" method of resolving duplicate linker symbols.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, but then the compiler and linker would have to have some way of communicating which symbols were inline functions (and so could safely have an arbitrary one picked) and which were normal functions (for which it would be preferable to diagnose duplicate symbols). Obviously it could be done, but what would be the point?

Comment: The "Pick Any" attribute is precisely that way of communicating. I agree that this case would be insufficient grounds to invent "Pick Any" had it not existed yet.

Answer (score 0):

It prevents user error. If you **intended** to write an `inline` function, but the compiler silently ignores you because you still put the definition in the .cpp file, then it would be difficult for you to spot the mistake. The program would still run, but slower.